# Is there something special in windows MSZIP format or CFDATA in cab files?

Tags: php, compression, binaryfiles, cab

I'm reading cab files in PHP and faced a problem during extraction.
All cab structure is finely parsed, but when I get compressed (with deflate method rfc 1951) data and `gzinflate()` on it, something strange happens:
First block of every folder is decompressed without any problems, but if I try to decompress any of N+1 block, gzinflate fails on it.

I checked that script rightly selects data (I look for `CK` tags) and uses right offsets.

## Format

**To understand problem let me describe cab and mszip format.** [see more at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb417343.aspx]

**CAB-file contains**:

1. **HEADER** structure
2. N of **FOLDER** structure
3. N of **FILE** structure
4. N of **DATA** structure

**FILE** structure has following fields:

- **folderId**
- **inFolderOffset**
- **uncompressedSize**

**DATA** is a compressed data portions. It also belongs to specific **folder** and has following fields:

- **folderId**
- **compressedSize**
- **uncompressedSize**
- **uncompressedOffset**

To extract any file content need:

1. Read and decompresses blocks in which this file present

   ```
   +----------+----------+             +----------+----------+----------+
   |  block 0 |  block 1 |             |  block 0 |  block 1 |  block 2 |
   +----------+----------+             +----------+----------+----------+
         ===========                     ================================
         |   file  |                     |       file 0       |  file 1 |
         ===========                     ================================
   ```
2. Join decompressed blocks
3. Cut from fileOffset to fileOffset+fileSize

### MSZIP format

It's a deflate-compressed data with 2-byte prefix (`CK`). Detailed: http://interoperability.blob.core.windows.net/files/MS-MCI/[MS-MCI].pdf

One thing that can have value this is: **Decoding
trees MUST be discarded after each RFC 1951 block, but the history buffer MUST be maintained.** (7th page).

I dont know a lot about deflate compression, but I use for this gzinflate. Is this wrong? Does this mean that I should write another implementation of deflate decompressor?

## Here's code

https://github.com/wapmorgan/CabArchive/blob/master/src/CabArchive.php

**To check decompressing of any block just execute**:

```
<?php
$cab = new CabArchive('any-cab.cab');
// Next command decompress first MSZIP block - successfully
$cab->decompressBlocks(0, [0]);
// And this command failed with "data error"
$cab->decompressBlocks(0, [1]);
```

Comment: Can you post any code? It is easier to help that way.

Comment: Add those references in your question, also add example to your error.

Comment: I found this sentence: **Whenever a cabinet folder boundary is reached, the compression history is discarded, so that decoding any folder does not require any prior data.**. This describes why first block of any folder is successfully unpacks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to feed the last 32K bytes uncompressed (or all of them if less than 32K) to the inflation of the next entry as a preset dictionary. The PHP function `inflate_init` supports this. *However see comments -- `inflate_init` may be buggy.*

Also you need to provide all zeros as the initial dictionary for the first inflation.

Comment: Ok, I try this:
`$context = inflate_init(ZLIB_ENCODING_RAW, ($block_id > 0) ? array('dictionary' => str_word_count($this->blocksRaw[$folderId][$block_id - 1], 1)) : array());`
Did you mean that?

Comment: All code is: https://github.com/wapmorgan/CabArchive/blob/master/src/CabArchive.php#L250
But this doesn't work right

Comment: Here I split previous block (32k text) to words and pass it as array.

Comment: Split? Words? Array? The dictionary is simply a sequence of 32K (or less) bytes, exactly as they were uncompressed.

Comment: If I pass raw uncompressed data from first block in `inflate_init` to decompress second block, with deleting NULL-bytes in data, it does not work.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "deleting NULL-bytes". php strings can contain null (0x00) bytes.

Comment: I posted code that involves only zlib. It does not work.
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/80878c6f8872adbad7a9c84c7de049d3db556751

Comment: `inflate_init` says it's bad: `PHP Warning:  inflate_init(): dictionary string must not contain empty entries (two consecutive NULL-bytes or one at the very beginning)`

Comment: Then that's a bug in PHP.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133216/discussion-between-wapmorgan-and-mark-adler).

Comment: Oh, that's not how it should be? `The dictionary should consist of strings (byte sequences)` (from zlib manual) Are we talking about something else than normal zero terminated C strings here? … is a dictionary just a single chunk of bytes without restrictions on content?

Comment: Yes, a deflate dictionary is just a bunch of bytes.

Comment: On a bug page (https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=73944) we can't decode second block of data even without php-specific restrictions for dictionary.

Comment: @MarkAdler, can you give an opinion?

Comment: What's wrong with php's inflate_init(). We still [dont know](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=73944) how to get it work.

Comment: The current PHP code appears to be calling `inflateSetDictionary()` only if `Z_DICT` is returned by deflate. The PHP code should also call `inflateSetDictionary()` after calling `inflateInit2()` if raw inflate is being requested.